# Keras - Plot training, validation and test set accuracy

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras

I want to plot the output of this simple neural network:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_test, y_test, nb_epoch=10, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)

model.test_on_batch(x_test, y_test)
model.metrics_names
```

I have plotted *accuracy* and *loss* of training and validation:

```
print(history.history.keys())
#  "Accuracy"
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# "Loss"
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Now I want to add and plot test set's accuracy from `model.test_on_batch(x_test, y_test)`, but from `model.metrics_names` I obtain the same value *'acc'* utilized for plotting accuracy on training data `plt.plot(history.history['acc'])`. How could I plot test set's accuracy?

Comment: Probable source of the original code: [Display Deep Learning Model Training History in Keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/display-deep-learning-model-training-history-in-keras/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it this way also ....

```
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
earlyStopCallBack = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=3)
history=regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs = EPOCHS, batch_size = BATCHSIZE, callbacks=[earlyStopCallBack])
```

For the plotting - I like plotly ... so

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Create figure with secondary y-axis
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter( y=history.history['val_loss'], name="val_loss"),
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter( y=history.history['loss'], name="loss"),
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter( y=history.history['val_accuracy'], name="val accuracy"),
    secondary_y=True,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter( y=history.history['accuracy'], name="val accuracy"),
    secondary_y=True,
)

# Add figure title
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Loss/Accuracy of LSTM Model"
)

# Set x-axis title
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Epoch")

# Set y-axes titles
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>primary</b> Loss", secondary_y=False)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>secondary</b> Accuracy", secondary_y=True)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Nothing wrong with either of the proceeding methods. Please note the Plotly graph has two scales , 1 for loss the other for accuracy.

Answer (score 146):

```
import keras
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
history = model1.fit(train_x, train_y,validation_split = 0.1, epochs=50, batch_size=4)
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: Model Accuracy]

```
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: Model Loss]

Comment: Just a small addition: In updated Keras and Tensorflow 2.0, the keyword acc and val_acc have been changed to accuracy and val_accuracy accordingly.

So, 
`plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])`

should be changed to 
`plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])`

(N.B. I am using Keras version 2.2.4)

Comment: I realized this and came back here to comment the same and I see you have already done that. That is SO is so great !

Comment: @EMT It does not depend on the Tensorflow version to use 'accuracy' or 'acc'. It depends on your own naming. `tf.version.VERSION` gives me `'2.4.1'`. I used 'accuracy' as the key and still got `KeyError: 'accuracy'`, but 'acc' worked. If you use `metrics=["acc"]`, you will need to call `history.history['acc']`.  If you use `metrics=["categorical_accuracy"]` in case of `loss="categorical_crossentropy"`, you would have to call `history.history['categorical_accuracy']`, and so on. See `history.history.keys()` for all options.

Answer (score 44):

Try

```
pd.DataFrame(history.history).plot(figsize=(8,5))
plt.show()
```

This builds a graph with the available metrics of the history for all datasets of the history. Example:

[image]

Answer (score 25):

It is the same because you are training on the test set, not on the train set. Don't do that, just train on the training set:

```
history = model.fit(x_test, y_test, nb_epoch=10, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

Change into:

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=10, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I always have utilized training set to train the NN, it's been an oversight. I am new in machine learning, and I am little bit confused about the result of  `model.fit( ... )`, I get _loss_,  _acc_, _val__loss_ and  _val__acc_, I suppose that values represent loss and accuracy on training and validation, but where can I find the value of loss about the test?

Comment: @Simone You can use model.evaluate on the test set to get the loss and metrics over the test set. Just make you sure use the right variables.

Comment: I have used _model.evaluete_, and I get _accuracy_ and _loss_, but I can't plot them because I can't distinguish  _accuracy_ obtained on training, from _accuracy_ obtained  on test.

Comment: @Simone What do you mean can't distinguish?

Comment: I should have an accuracy on training, an accuracy on validation, and an accuracy on test; but I get only two values: _val__acc_  and _acc_, respectively for validation and training. From `model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)` 
`model.metrics_names` I get _acc_, the same of training. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Simone We don't have enough information to tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134279/discussion-between-simone-and-matias-valdenegro).

Answer (score 10):

Validate the model on the test data as shown below and then plot the accuracy and loss

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), shuffle=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use `accuracy` and `val_accuracy` while plotting chart

---

### Plotting `accuracy` in [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) :

```
plt.plot(model.history.history["accuracy"], label="training accuracy")
plt.plot(model.history.history["val_accuracy"], label="validation accuracy")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: accuracy graph]

### Plotting `loss` in [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) :

```
plt.plot(model.history.history["loss"], label="training loss")
plt.plot(model.history.history["val_loss"], label="validation loss")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: loss graph]